# How to Fix cannot resolve method 'setContentView' in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to write an Android App and all seems to work except for one line i.e. 'setContentView'

Is there a way I could substitute the above function

This is the code in question and the problem is in line **18**

```
public class HiraFragment extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hira,null);
}

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;
ImageView logo;
ImageView bg;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    logo = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.logo);
    bg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.bg);
    text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
    web.setWebViewClient(new hira());
    web.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


}



public class hira extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logo.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        bg.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        text.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
    }



}
```

}

All the app is to do is to have a bottom navigation bar and bring up a loading screen and then display a webpage in a webview

Could someone please help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you are mixing fragments and activity, both works differently so read and decide what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you have made is a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`, but your `onCreate` method looks like it was copied from an Activity. There is no `setContentView` method in a Fragment.

You would set the layout in `onCreateView` and set up other things in, say, `onActivityCreated` or `onCreateView` itself. For example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hira, container, false);

    // To access the views, you need to prefix them with the rootView like this
    web = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    logo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    bg = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bg);
    text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text); 

    web.setWebViewClient(new hira());
    web.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    return rootView;
}
```

Take a look at the Android guide for Fragments [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating), or use an Activity instead.